# "Simplicial" Bordism Homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplicial-complex, cobordism

I have been trying to figure out if there is an analogous theory using Cobordism to simplicial homology. That is we consider closed submanifolds of a space X directly, as one considers simplices of a simplicial complex directly in simplicial homology. Looking into this, the biggest problem seems to be the operation on the "group", since we can't use a disjoint union of the submanifolds, and their union may not be a closed.

I thought to fix this problem we could consider submanifolds up to homotopy, so that if their intersection mod 2 number was 0 we would be fine. Then this could work over manifolds whose submanifolds always have intersection number 0.

Does this theory already exist? Is the above stated property sufficient? I am having a bit of an issue proving that it is an equivalence relation under only that assumption. If the above might work, what kind of manifolds have this property if any? It seems like $\mathbb{R}^n$ and maybe spheres, at least $S^2$. I wonder if this is true for S^n?

EDIT: Mod 2 intersection theory may not work here, what we truly need is a manifold M with the property that ever pair of k-dimensional submanifolds may be homotoped apart over M.

Comment: What is the intersection number of a submanifold? If you are thinking of selfintersections I prefer to think of the selfintersection as a homotopy class of a submanifold itself (only if the dimension is even you can cook up a reasonable number out of selfintersections of submanifolds).

Comment: I've been thinking about this a little more, and I guess mod 2 intersection theory isn't enough due to the dimension assumptions in it. What we really need is a space whose k-dimensional submanifolds may all be homotoped to be disjoint

Comment: If you want something that in the ends computes the classical bordism of a space, you should think a bit about the bordism groups of a point.

Comment: If you want your edit to hold over all $k$ you will be out of luck: For an $n$ dimensional manifold there will always be an $n$ dimensional manifold which cannot be homotoped away from itself (namely the manifold itself)

Comment: You could have a look at the book of Kreck about stratifolds, maybe this is interesting to you.

Comment: Good points, I think I only need k<n thankfully, because the boundary map into the nth dimension is obviously 0, so you don't need to condition for it to be well defined.